# Cannot scroll inside mobile page

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile

I've tried multiple things, including taking out the preventDefaults's and implementing a js that would force touch scrolling but it has all failed. What I am trying to do is keep the blue bar at the top of this page fixed and allow the page to scroll. Eventually I want to add a transition that will only affect the scrollable area but currently I have been trying to figure out why this page won't scroll vertically.

Here is the html:
http://jsbin.com/ocijax

Here is the source:
http://jsbin.com/ocijax/edit#javascript,html

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I just have a really bad feeling the solution has been right in front of my face. Thank you!